# android toast printing strange numbers instead of words

Tags: android, toast

For the following toast, why the following code

```
Toast message = Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.message_saved + savedFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

showing some strange numbers , eg 2131099680 /mnt/sdcard/*the path* instead of the desired "your image is saved at: /mnt/sdcard/*the path*?

How could this be modified? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put both your Strings together *before* making the Toast by using [`Context#getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) to get the `String` from a String resource id:

```
String text = getContext().getString(R.string.message_saved) + savedFilePath;

Toast message =  Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Before you were printing out the int representation of `R.string.message_saved` which is actually what is in R, just integers.

Alternatively, you can skip using the String `text` by putting

```
getContext().getString(R.string.message_saved) + savedFilePath;
```

directly in the `Toast`'s second argument, but I did it with a separate String for *clarity*.

My above answer used `getContext()` since the OP is extending `View`. [`View` has this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29), so it is a valid way of getting the `Context` in this scenario. The important thing to note though, is that the real problem was not choosing how to get the `Context` (which, if you're inside an Activity rather than a `View,` passing off the `Activity` instance to `makeText()` will suffice), but instead how to get the `String` from a *String resource id*.

Comment: @pearmak no problem, thanks for being so quick! One question: is `getContext()` a custom method, or are you extending `View`, or something similar? I based my answer on your code in the question, but it's bound to annoy *someone* in the future if I don't talk about how `getContext()` isn't normal a part of `Activity`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources.getString(R.string.imgval), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).toShow();
```